# Figurative meaning of "conduit"

Tags: word-meaning

> Conduit: a means of transmitting or distributing ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conduit))

Take this sentence as an example:

Ultimately, you become a fundamental **conduit** between the data teams and decision-makers in management.

I understand this means you are a channel of communication between them. But does it imply you negotiate between them and perhaps bridge their understanding gap? Or does it simply mean you pass information along without doing anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything more explicit than that you conduct something, in this case information. The words "conduit" and "conduct" are etymological doublets in English, having the same Latin root.

However, someone using that term could use it to partially describe an organizational position with a more complicated role.

Comment: There is a "specialty" called "knowledge translation" (or "knowledge brokering", and there are likely other names used, especially in other fields or locations), where people bridge two areas of expertise.  In government, for example, people who have science and policy backgrounds are helpful to explain science to upper executives in the civil service and to politicians (who often have no science background) and to explain policy rationale to scientists..  This is much more than acting as a conduit though.